# Printing out Numbers between a set Min and Max

Tags: c, arrays, numbers, printf, min

I am trying to create a function that takes a set min and max values and then prints out the numbers of a given array that fit between those values. Here is my code:

```
void clampNums( const double* i_origArray, int i_size,
double i_min, double i_max )
{
    printf("clampNums(): Start\n");
    for (int i=0; i<i_size; i++)
    {
        if (i_min < i_origArray[i] < i_max)
        {
            printf("%f ", i_origArray[i]);
        }

    }

    printf("clampNums(): End\n");
}


int main()
{
    int size = 6;
    double cMin = 0.0, cMax = 10.0;
    double arr[] = { 1.33, -0.06, 20.54, -4.49, -39.0, 0.000001 };

    printf("Clamping min = %f, max = %f\n", cMin, cMax);
    printf("Original array:\n\t");
    for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
        {
            printf("%f, ", arr[i]);
        }
    printf("\n");

    clampNums(arr, size, cMin, cMax );

    return 0;
}
```

Im struggling to figure out how to get my for loop to work inside my ClampNums() function. It just keeps printing out all the values, not the ones between the min and max. Any ideas?

Comment: Would you bother to tell us why you add `python` and `C`?
The example code is written in C? So any need for python code?

Comment: That was a mistake. I have removed that tag now. No need for python code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`if (i_min < i_origArray[i] < i_max)` is probably not what you want.  If you want to check the range use the following:

```
if ((i_min < i_origArray[i]) && (i_origArray[I] < i_max))
```